# QTcpServer listening on address 0.0.0.0

Tags: qt

I have following code chunk for starting `QTcpServer`:

```
void UeConnectionServer::ueStartConnectionServer()
{
    QString logText=QString();

    if(!this->isListening())
    {
        if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,
                         1234))
        {
            logText=tr("[ERROR]").append(" ")
                                 .append(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz"))
                                 .append(" ")
                                 .append(this->errorString());

            emit this->ueSignalEventInfoAdded(logText);
        }
        else
        {
            logText=tr("[INFO]").append(" ")
                                .append(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz"))
                                .append(" ")
                                .append(tr("Server started on address ")
                                .append(this->serverAddress().toString())
                                .append(":")
                                .append(QString::number(this->serverPort())));

            emit this->ueSignalEventInfoAdded(logText);
        }   // if
    }   // if
}   // ueStartConnectionServer
```

The server is started successfully, however, the following log line shows it is listening on address `0.0.0.0`:

> [INFO] 25.03.2016 12:02:36:265 Server started on address 0.0.0.0:1234

Why does `QTcpServer` not gain workstation's IP, for my case `192.168.0.100`. I am using `Linux` and here is `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:6f:65:92:82:02  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:18984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3979893 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:3979893 (3.9 MB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:172.16.115.1  Bcast:172.16.115.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:327 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:192.168.77.1  Bcast:192.168.77.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:fd:b9:2d:cc:90  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6efd:b9ff:fe2d:cc90/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1047445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:583455 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1267590187 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:99542638 (99.5 MB)
```

Is it maybe the problem that `QTcpServer` tries to get `IP address` from **first** network interface in the list and **not the active** one?

Comment: What are you talking about? You asked the server to listen on `QHostAddress::Any`, which means listening to the `0.0.0.0` address (i.e. on **any interface**).

Comment: @peppe yes I've asked it to listen to `QHostAddress::Any` and it is listening to `0.0.0.0`, but why is `this->serverAddress().toString()` also returning `0.0.0.0`, it should return my active interface IP, i.e. `192.168.0.100`?

Comment: Because you didn't bind to that interface, you bound to *any* interface. If another interface comes up with another IP, you'd be bound to that too. Even if the existing one goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the QT documentation says so: [QHostAddress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostaddress.html)

> QHostAddress::Any: The IPv4 any-address. Equivalent to
>   QHostAddress("0.0.0.0").

You don't have to worry, your server listens on all IP addresses it has. You have multiple network interfaces. From all of them you can reach them, if you specify  192.168.0.100 you will limit the server to only 1 network interface.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get `IP address` of workstation server running on it? I would like to get which `IP address` is server process/app listening from!

Comment: You already have it (via ifconfig). From all the network interfaces specified. So in vmnet1 (172.16.115.1), vmnet8(192.168.77.1), wlan0(192.168.0.100)

Comment: ok, but I want to get `IP address` of **active interface** from `Qt` code, so I can notify user, which `IP address` and which `Port` is my server app listening from!

Comment: You have **multiple** active interfaces. You can use `QNetworkInterface` to enumerate them, and/or listen on just a subset of them. Still you'd need to tell the user all the IPs you picked.